# Swaying table when I write on it with even small pressure

Tags: tabletop

I made the wooden study table myself. The top is flat 1200 mm board and added wooden legs with the top flat board. The legs have been joined together at the bottom as well like a rectangular U shape. What can I do to make it not sway or move.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. We need a little more detail than this, e.g. how are all the various pieces joined together??! But before you edit your Question to add more details and a couple of photos, have you tried a search here on SE? We have multiple previous Q&As on wobbly tables, mounting tabletops to legs and general table design, any one of which might give you the information you need. But certainly all together you will find a suitable answer.

Comment: Research using the keyword "racking" and get back to us if that doesn't suffice. https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/search?q=racking